implementing an overall Wald test for a glmer model
I would like to know how to get the overall Wald test and its p-value for a fitted glmer model from the lme4 package. For example:
credec ~ passexp + soctie + recexp + peer + soctie * recexp + 
   (1 | region), data = data, family = binomial

Also, how would one obtain the likelihood ratio test value of the model as a whole?

You can do a likelihood ratio test of the full model by using anova() to compare a full model to an intercept-only model.  Usually you want to retain the random effects:
data("Owls", package = "glmmTMB")
library(lme4)
m <- glmer(SiblingNegotiation ~ ArrivalTime*SexParent + (1|Nest),
           data = Owls, family = poisson)
m0 <- update(m, . ~ 1 + (1|Nest))
anova(m, m0)

If you want to remove the random effects as well you need to use glm() for the null model (and you must put the mixed model first in the anova() call):
g <- glm(SiblingNegotiation ~ 1, data = Owls, family = poisson)
anova(m, g)

You can use aod::wald.test (for example) to jointly test all the fixed effect parameters:
library(aod)
beta <- fixef(m)
wald.test(vcov(m), beta, Terms = 1:length(beta))

